# IIS Timeout in WIndows 10 after a few requests

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am running Windows 10 and IIS 10.0.14393.0, and have two sites running in the same app pool. Both are Visual Studio MVC 5 projects, one for the site UI, and the other a WebAPI instance that connects to a SQL database.

When I load one page (for instance), a grid is populated it sends subsequent requests to fill in images on each row of a list. It will process one image after loading the page and then hang / error on the rest. It is not specific to any particular request. I also have an update that performs multiple requests, and it happens there.

The error I am getting returned is Operation Canceled, but in the stack trace below, it seems to be indicating an Owin error at the root. I can cancel the requests from the browser, and attempt to load a different page, but it will do nothing until I either wait it out (about 2 min), or stop and start the web site.

This also occurs on another page where there are multiple requests. It doesn't seem related to the request, only if the request ends up waiting behind another query. I have isolated it to my box, as other devs are running the same exact project and project settings and do not have this issue.

I have also tried pointing the Web Site to an Azure instance of the WebAPI with success.

While the site is hung, I can switch over to SSMS and query the same data without issue. I believe this is an IIS issue, but not sure how to sort it out.

Also while the site is hung, I am unable to bring up elmah errors hosted on the same site. So no request is allowed through.

I had read something about some request causing IIS to close the connection and not allow it to open based on some issue it detects. I don't remember where I saw that.

EDIT:

Not sure why, but the timeouts I mentioned below I think are misleading. Here is an actual stack trace of when it originally starts failing. While this is happening, if I try to bring up another page, Chrome puts in its status bar "Waiting for available socket"

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.    at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()   at System.Web.Http.HostAuthenticationFilter.<AuthenticateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Owin.PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)    at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Attach the debugger and pause it during the hang. Find out what all the threads are doing. Where are they stuck? If there are no threads busy it might be a async IO, possibly deadlocked.

Comment: Every thread that didn't say Location "not available" was sitting on System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive, except for one which was at System.dll!System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc.

Comment: Subsequent breaks had all threads at "not available" except for the one at System.dll!System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc

Comment: That's what "no thread is busy" looks like. Post the HTTP response that a timeout produces. Are there any exceptions when you set the debugger to halt on all exception?

Comment: I caught this on elmah -- System.Net.WebException The request was aborted: The operation has timed out. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()... More later.

Comment: That's something *you* are calling timing out. It's not the browser or IIS timing out.

Comment: I had a little more time and clarified the issue above (hopefully).

Comment: Where is the WebException? "operation was canceled" usually is a timeout. This looks like the ASP.NET request timeout.

Comment: I see several of these errors, and no other error in the exceptions elmah has recorded. When I have more time, I will see if I can catch something else via debug.

Comment: This is difficult because due to all the asyncness you can't just pause the debugger to see what is happening. This is a major downside to async IO. You need to find out why your requests are taking so long that they time out. Likely, the outbound HTTP request you are doing times out which is the WebException .

Comment: The situation is indiscriminate toward what the request is - I can repro this in several different situations and the first two or three calls work fine and the rest do this. The errors above are timing out on a call to retrieve an image. It is local, and if I call it discretely (not stacked behind another request) it comes back in a half second or less. Really frustrating issue. Thanks for all your input so far.